# SQL to HiveQL conversion

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have this SQL query and I am trying to convert it so that it can be run on HiveQL 2.1.1.

```
SELECT p.id FROM page p, comments c, users u,

WHERE c.commentid= p.id 
AND u.id = p.creatorid 
AND u.upvotes IN (
    SELECT MAX(upvotes)
    FROM users u WHERE u.date > p.date
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM links l WHERE l.relid > p.id
)
```

This does not work on Hive QL, as it has more than 1 SubQuery (which is not supported)

`EXISTS` or `IN` replacements from SQL to Hive SQL are done like this:

```
WHERE A.aid IN (SELECT bid FROM B...)
```

can be replaced by:

```
A LEFT SEMI JOIN B ON aid=bid
```

But I can`t come up with a way to do this with the additional **MAX()** function.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.  Why are you including the `comments` table.  No columns are being used.

Comment: basically the problem lies in rewriting the IN part. everything else (data etc. can basically be ignored). The comments table is needed just for this `WHERE c.commentid= p.id`  but to rewrite the IN statement it could be ignored ...

Answer (score 0):

Use standard join syntax instead of comma separated :

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM page p INNER JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.commentid= p.id INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = p.creatorid INNER JOIN
     links l 
     ON l.relid > p.id 
WHERE u.upvotes IN (SELECT MAX(upvotes)
                    FROM users u 
                    WHERE u.date > p.date
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer! Unfortunately due to a limitation with Hive 2.1, inequalities are not allowed in the ON clause and i get an error:  Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the `upvotes` logic is supposed to be doing.  The `links` logic is easy to handle.  Hive may handle this:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM page p JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.commentid = p.id JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = p.creatorid CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(l.relid) as max_relid
      FROM links l
     ) l
WHERE l.max_relid > p.id AND
      u.upvotes IN (SELECT MAX(upvotes)
                    FROM users u
                    WHERE u.date > p.date
                   );
```

Comment: unfortunately hive will report "SemanticException [Error 10249]: Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'date': SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition.